# Testing Kotlin Flows with shareIn()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, turbine

I'm trying to test a Flow that uses `shareIn` with Turbine, but I'm a bit lost why my tests are failing and how I can fix it.

```kotlin
class MyTest {

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    private val mutableSharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

    @Test
    fun succeeds() = runBlocking {
        val sharedFlow = mutableSharedFlow

        sharedFlow.test {
            expectNoEvents()
            mutableSharedFlow.emit(3)
            expect(expectItem()).toBe(3)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun fails() = runBlocking {
        val sharedFlow = mutableSharedFlow
            .shareIn(scope, started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed())

        sharedFlow.test {
            expectNoEvents()
            mutableSharedFlow.emit(3)
            expect(expectItem()).toBe(3)
        }
    }
}
```

In these tests, the first `succeeds()` test runs fine, but as soon as I include `shareIn` in the `fails()` test, the test fails with a timeout:

```
Timed out waiting for 1000 ms
kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 1000 ms
    (Coroutine boundary)
    at app.cash.turbine.ChannelBasedFlowTurbine$expectEvent$2.invokeSuspend(FlowTurbine.kt:238)
    at app.cash.turbine.ChannelBasedFlowTurbine$withTimeout$2.invokeSuspend(FlowTurbine.kt:206)
    at app.cash.turbine.ChannelBasedFlowTurbine.expectItem(FlowTurbine.kt:243)
```

What should I do to test flows that use `shareIn`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know why you've decided to use a scope with `Dispatchers.Default` as here:

```
...
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
...
```

For tests, just use `Dispatchers.Unconfined` instead because it executes coroutines immediately on the current thread and that's exactly what you need there.

```
...
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
...
```

So, after applying the change above, both of your tests passed successfully.

You can find my sample project for this question [here](https://github.com/Tester2012/stackoverflow).

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing!

Comment: Thanks bro! i was trying to test a corroutine with the default dispatcher and it wasnt covering inside the methods. That answer saved the day!